# Typescript - How to infer generic in non-invoked function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

See the example below; it should be working by all reasonable interpretation of the code. Does anybody have any insight on why it doesn't?

[TS-playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMA%20gJwKZQWyBJMABwVgF4YAKASyJIC4Zo0aBzAShgYAU0QBbKhAwAeJqwB8MUpJ79BGAHSYIIADYA3DNVpQ2AbgBQBqAE9CGGJmy4IBYlBQAVKTGGPxFACYBDKN4aOHNIwsgJCbuKGRqCQsFAY0AxWOPg6Ti6IyOhYKbY6hkA)

```
const func_returnsInput = (input: string) : Promise<string> => Promise.resolve(input);

type returnsInput_T = <T>(data: T) => Promise<T>;

const test: returnsInput_T = func_returnsInput;

**ERROR**
Type '(input: string) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'returnsInput_T'.
  Types of parameters 'input' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type signature of `func_returnsInput` is:

```
const func_returnsInput: (input: string) => Promise<string>
```

That is specifically a function that accepts a `string` (and only a `string`) and returns a `Promise<string>`.  You could change the implementation slightly and it would still conform to the annotated type signature:

```
const func_returnsInput = (input: string): Promise<string> =>
    Promise.resolve(input.toUpperCase());
```

The fact that the implementation *doesn't* do that is not important to the compiler. It considers the call signature to be the externally-viewable type of the function, and any specific implementation to be hidden.  If someone hands me `func_returnsInput`, all I know is that it takes a `string` and returns a `Promise<string>`.  If I were to feed it, say, a `number`, then I have done something wrong.

---

Contrast that now with the type `ReturnsInput_T`:

```
type ReturnsInput_T = <T>(data: T) => Promise<T>;
```

That is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) call signature with a generic type parameter `T`.  **The type parameter may be specified at will by the *caller* of the function, not by the *implementer* of the function.**  The type `ReturnsInput_T` is a function that accepts any value the caller wants (say, a `number`), and then returns a `Promise` of the same data type (so, `Promise<number>`).

If it helps, you can think of a generic call signature as an infinite [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of all possible types for `T`.  You can't write that out, but it behaves like

```
type ReturnsInput_T_Infinite =
    & ((data: string) => Promise<string>) 
    & ((data: number) => Promise<number>)
    & ((data: boolean) => Promise<boolean>)
    & ((data: Date) => Promise<Date>)
    & ((data: null) => Promise<null>)
    // & ...
```

---

Now it hopefully makes sense why you cannot assign `func_returnsInput` to a value of type `ReturnsInput`:

```
const test: ReturnsInput_T = func_returnsInput; // error!
// Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.

test(123); // no error
```

If `test` is truly of type `ReturnsInput_T`, then I should be allowed to call `test(123)`, or `test(false)` or `test(new Date())` or anything I want, and get back a `Promise` of the same data type.  But `func_returnsInput` cannot be known to do that by the compiler (even if the implementation happens to do this).

And so you get an error!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwK4RAfQE4FMZI9ASQgAcl4BeOACgEsSyAuOWDOgcwEomAFDMAWxpQsAHhbsAfHHITgceXF4ChWAHTYoYADYA3LLXoxVMMAFVixLBgDCAQ2FUOHANzBgMAJ6W4AJRx5CQzQAFWk4EWCJKgATWxhbJmCOaSklQWEIiVc3T28-XHwoIlIYELQiBDoaGCxpOQUAMmoYuITmGFYIThTFPnTRcS6JZPr5JqoW+KYIJH4AIytkmV7lDJn5q2HRuHHJtrmwbSxbCCXUvpURA6OTrYUd5tipuAAROKwzlf6RN5q7xserWmSC0Wk+aUuM1B-3kAHpYQ9VEi3OBoPAarAmPkAkUgqFKMhUJh-IVimRXPC4MEvLUAOTBWlwIRwCBgeD2KA0NgQWxzLS1ExwXJ0wZsWmqdxYWBUACMACYAMwuOCUqAACzAIOicAWcDAAGtbB4gA)

Comment: Thanks, do you know a way to use explicit types but constrain the output to be the same as the input (while still using inference).

Comment: If by "explicit" you mean "non-generic", then no. Generics are how you represent that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you want to use the type of a function that takes a generic with a function that takes explicitly a string. The following works for me:

```
type returnsInput_T = <T>(data: T) => Promise<T>;


function func_returnsInput<T>(input: T) {
    return Promise.resolve(input)
}

const test: returnsInput_T = func_returnsInput;
```

Hope it helped